# Opencart - "Страница, которую Вы запрашиваете, не найдена."

Tags: php, opencart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После установки модуля popup корзины на Opencart возникла ошибка, То есть при загрузке страницы модулей выдает текст:

> "Страница, которую Вы запрашиваете, не найдена. Если проблема будет
>   повторяться, свяжитесь пожалуйста с администратором."

Срочно нужна помощь. Так как почти всё на мой взгляд перепробовал. Восстановил резервку всего сайта, включая БД- не помогло

Comment: прикрепите скрин ошибки а так же посмотрите лог-ошибок "system-tools-error log", что там есть?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, ошибка как я понял просто 404. Что за страница модулей в опенкарте?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin,прикрепил,вот что выдает в консоли " Синхронный XMLHttpRequest в основном потоке является устаревшим из-за его пагубного влияния на работу конечного пользователя. Для получения дополнительной помощи обратитесь к http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/".Журнал ошибок опенкарта не  выдал никаких ошибок

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev,прикрепил изображение

Comment: Решили проблему? У меня такая же проблема

Comment: решил..........................